# Dependency Injection in Angular 2 with ES5

Tags: angular, dependency-injection

Suppose I've got two separate `components`. One defines the `my-app` element, one defines the `child` element.

I want the `child` component to be a dependency of the `my-app` (root) component.

How is this done?

**myapp.component.js**

```
(function(app) {
  app.AppComponent = ng.core
    .Component({
      selector: 'my-app',
      template: '<h1>My First Angular 2 App!!</h1>'
    })
    .Class({
      constructor: function() {}
    });
})(window.app || (window.app = {}));
```

**child.component.js**

```
(function(app) {
  app.ChildComponent = ng.core
    .Component({
      selector: 'child',
      template: '<h3>This is the child</h3>',

    })
    .Class({
      constructor: function() {}
    });
})(window.app || (window.app = {}));
```

Comment: I Don't know about using .js but yes you have.to import child component in the parent component to use it. and also you have provide that components in the directive list in the @component annotation. then you can easily use that child component in your parent component. i hope you got some clue from this. yes also if you need i will provide the example of parent child component usage as the answer.

Comment: But in es5 you don't have annotations

Answer (score 1):

In fact, it's something similar to what we have in the Typescript version ;-). You need to configure providers:

- At the application-level within the `bootstrap` method
- At the component-level within the `providers` property

There are two great blog posts that can help you when writing Angular2 applications with ES5:

- http://gurustop.net/blog/2015/12/16/angular2-beta-javascript-component by Meligy
- http://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2015/05/09/writing-angular-2-code-in-es5.html by Pascal Precht
- http://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2015/07/06/even-better-es5-code-for-angular-2.html by Pascal Precht

Here is a complete working sample with ES5 only:

- **index.html** for JavaScript files to include

  ```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
    <head>
      <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/2.0.0-beta.0/Rx.umd.js"></script>
      <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/2.0.0-beta.0/angular2-polyfills.js"></script>
      <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/2.0.0-beta.0/angular2-all.umd.dev.js"></script>
      <script src="main.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
      <cmp>&lt;/cmp>
    </body>
  </html>
  ```
- **Definition of the service**

  ```
  var Service = function() {};
  Service.prototype.greeting = function() {
    return 'hello';
  };
  ```
- **Definition of the component**

  ```
  var Cmp = 
    ng.core.Component({
      selector: 'cmp'
  }).
  View({
    template: '{{greeting}} world!'
  }).
  Class({
    constructor: [Service, function(service) {
      this.greeting = service.greeting();
    }]
  });
  ```
- **Bootstrap the `Cmp` component** as application component

  ```
  document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    ng.platform.browser.bootstrap(Cmp);
  });
  ```
- **Dependency injection at application level**. Simply add a second parameter to the `bootstrap` function. Its value corresponds to an array containing the `Service` object.

  ```
  document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    ng.platform.browser.bootstrap(Cmp, [Service]);
  });
  ```
- **Dependency injection at component level**. Simply add a `providers` property in the component configuration object. Its value is an array containing the `Service` object.

  ```
  var Cmp = ng.core.
  Component({
    selector: 'cmp',
    providers: [Service]
  }).
  View({
    template: '{{greeting}} world!'
  }).
  Class({
    constructor: [Service, function(service) {
      this.greeting = service.greeting();
    }]
  });
  ```

If you want to use a component inside another one, simply leverage the `directives` attribute of the view, as described below. The `CmpChild` component is used within the `Cmp` one.

```
var CmpChild = ng.core.
  Component({
    selector: 'child'
  }).
  View({
    template: '{{greeting}} world!'
  }).
  Class({
    constructor: [Service, function(service) {
      this.greeting = service.greeting();
    }]
  });

var Cmp = ng.core.
  Component({
    selector: 'cmp'
  }).
  View({
    template: '<child></child>',
    directives: [CmpChild]
  }).
  Class({
    constructor: [Service, function(service) {

    }]
  });
```

Hope it helps you,
Thierry