# How to inject upgraded Angular 1 service/factory to Angular 2 component in ES5?

Tags: angularjs, angular

I have an Angular1 service with name, say, 'myService'

I then upgraded it using the Angular2 UpgradeAdapter like this:

```
var upgradeAdapter = new ng.upgrade.UpgradeAdapter();
upgradeAdapter.upgradeNg1Provider('myService');
```

Now I need to inject it to the angular2 component. Official upgrade guide only has typescript version for now. In typescript you use @Inject anotation with the service name for it like so:

```
export class MyComponent {
  constructor(@Inject('myService') service:MyService) {
    ...
  }
}
```

What is the syntax for injecting a service by name using ES5?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To complete the pixelbits' answer, you need also define my service within the providers list either:

- **At the application level**

  ```
  document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    ng.platform.browser.bootstrap(Cmp, [MyService]);
  });
  ```
- **At the component level**

  ```
  var Cmp = ng.core.
   Component({
     selector: 'cmp',
     providers: [ MyService ]
   }).
   (...)
   Class({
     constructor: [MyService, function(service) {
     }]
   });
  ```

It depends on what you want to do: share your service instance for all elements in the Angular2 application or per component.

This answers could give more details on dependency injection in Angular2 with ES5: [Dependency Injection in Angular 2 with ES5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34644887/dependency-injection-in-angular-2-with-es5/34653438#34653438).

**Edit**

In fact, there is a subtlety. IN the case of upgrade you need not to bootstrap using the `ng.platform.browser.bootstrap` function but the one from the `upgrade` object.

```
upgrade.bootstrap(document.body, ['heroApp']);
```

Where `heroApp` is the Angular1 module containing services and factories I want to use in the Angular2 application.

In fact, when you call the `upgradeNg1Provider` method on the upgrade, corresponding providers are registered within its associated injector. This means that you don't need to specify them at described above.

So you simply need to do that where you want to inject:

```
(...)
Class({
  constructor: [ ng.core.Inject('customService'),
                 ng.core.Inject('customFactory'),
                 function(cService, cFactory) {
  }]
});
```

Miško Hevery provides a great plunkr for this: http://plnkr.co/edit/yMjghOFhFWuY8G1fVIEg?p=preview.

Hope it helps you,
Thierry

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It looks like injection by type. But I don't actualy have the MyService class/function.The service is declared like this: myModule.factory('myService', [function () {...}]). Or this class/function is somehow created during the upgrade?

Comment: I can't make work with Angular1 factories. I expect to have something like that:  `constructor: [ new ng.core.Inject('customFactory'), function(cFactory) { (...) }]`. But I have the following error: `No provider for customFactory! (class1 -> customFactory)`. In fact, I don't know what to put within the providers list (application or component level). I made some tries with the `ng.core.provide` function without success...

Comment: I created an issue in Github for this: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/6588.

Comment: Miško Hevery answered the issue ;-) I updated my answer with a working solution...

Answer (score 2):

Use the array notation for constructor DI of services:

```
.Class({
    constructor: [MyService, function (service) {
      ...
 }],
```