# angular 1.x and angular2 together

Tags: angular

While working on converting my application to angular2 I am getting following error
When I am trying to use both Angular 1.4 and 2 together I am getting following error

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IZYtO.png)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know which JS files you included in your HTML file. Here are the ones I used:

```
<script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://rawgithub.com/systemjs/systemjs/0.19.6/dist/system.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.angularjs.org/2.0.0-beta.1/Rx.umd.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.angularjs.org/2.0.0-beta.1/angular2-polyfills.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.angularjs.org/2.0.0-beta.1/angular2-all.umd.dev.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.angularjs.org/2.0.0-beta.1/upgrade.js"></script>
```

The following answer and plunkr could give you more details about the way to initialize such applications (mixing Angular1 & Angular2 elements):

- [How to inject upgraded Angular 1 service/factory to Angular 2 component in ES5?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34900338/how-to-inject-upgraded-angular-1-service-factory-to-angular-2-component-in-es5/34901238#34901238)
- http://plnkr.co/edit/yMjghOFhFWuY8G1fVIEg?p=preview

Hope it helps you,
Thierry