# Use AngularJS (Angular1) module from Angular2 project

Tags: angularjs, angular

Just started a demo Angular2 project (no previous experience with Angular1/AngularJS. Have followed and extended from the online quickstart and tutorials, and all was fine. However I'm at the point where I would like to use some components from a library which is designed for AngularJS, and having no end of problems!

Most of the information available about AngularJS/Angular2 compatibility assumes that you have an AngularJS project that you're adding Angular2 components to - not the other way around - so what I'm hoping to do may not even be possible. What I've tried so far involves a simple stripped-back project based on the Angular2 quickstart, with a single Angular2 component that loads into the index.html. I'd then like to integrate components from the existing library (AngularJS-based) into this.

- I've tried using `UpgradeAdapter.upgradeNg1Component` to create components from the library and add them directly into my Angular2 component
- I've tried installing angularjs through npm, importing it in a script tag into my `index.html` and then using a combination of `UpgradeAdapter.downgradeNg2Component` and `UpgradeAdapter.bootstrap` to load my Angular2 as a downgraded module

Neither of these seem to work - the component fails to show, and the browser console tells me I've got an `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
    Evaluating http://localhost:3000/angular2/upgrade
    Error loading http://localhost:3000/app/main.js`

My best guess at the moment is that this is actually an unsupported scenario, and I need to have a 'proper' AngularJS app in order to use the `UpgradeAdapter` functionality from Angular2. Can anyone confirm this? Or is there something stupid I'm missing here?

Comment: @Bryan Thanks for that - it was my understanding that for an AngularJS/Angular2 hybrid app you _couldn't_ use the `ng-app` tag, and had to use the `bootstrap()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So the major problem in this case turned out to be the fact that it appears that the upgrade components aren't included as part of the basic angular 2 bundle. After adding:

`<script src="node_modules/angular2/bundles/upgrade.min.js"></script>`

to my index.html file the error I was seeing disappeared.

Thanks to the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34402203/2050479) for pointing me in the right direction!

Comment: Linking directly to your node_modules folder is a bad solution. Once you deploy your solution that folder is no longer there (assuming you're using some kind of bundling setup)

Answer (score 3):

Here is a working plunkr describing how to mix Angular1 and Angular2 elements:

- http://plnkr.co/edit/yMjghOFhFWuY8G1fVIEg?p=preview

An important point is to `bootstrap` your main component on the `UpgradeAdapter`. This way all elements are available in providers (services / factories) and in directives (components / directives):

```
upgrade.bootstrap(document.body, ['heroApp']);
```

These two answers could help you:

- [angular 1.x and angular2 together](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35017455/angular-1-x-and-angular2-together/35017780#35017780)
- [How to inject upgraded Angular 1 service/factory to Angular 2 component in ES5?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34900338/how-to-inject-upgraded-angular-1-service-factory-to-angular-2-component-in-es5/34901238#34901238)