# create an angular 2 service in es5

Tags: javascript, angular, angular2-services

Im trying to create a custom service in angular 2 but i can't seem to find any documentation on angular 2 services in es5 (which is what im writing my code in) i've tried using this

```
(function(app){
    app.database=ng.core.Injectable().Class({
        constructor:[function(){
            this.value="hello world";
        }],
        get:function(){return this.value},
    });
    ng.core.Injector.resolveAndCreate([app.database]);
    ng.core.provide(app.database,{useClass:app.database});
})(window.app||(window.app={}));
```

however when i inject it into my component it throws the error `no provider for class0 (class10 -> class0)` i can't seem to figure out how to create the custom service. does anyone know how to do this in es5?

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34532138/how-to-inject-custom-service-to-angular-component-in-plain-es5-javascript

Comment: i wasn't able to find that question thank you for the reference is there anysituation you would use Injector.resoveAndCreate or ng.core.provide?

Comment: I've never even seen `ng.core.Injectable` or `ng.core.Injector` documented - but I'm an angular2 noob :p

Comment: there isn't much documentation on them although what i have seen they seem to be the root of service providers but i don't know aside from that

Comment: im also curious if anyone knows why you don't need to use provides with ngRoute even though you do inject it into your component constructor

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a complete sample of dependency injection with ES5. (service into component, service into service). Don't forget to specify your service when bootstrapping your application or within the `providers` attribute of components.

```
var OtherService = function() {};
OtherService.prototype.test = function() {
  return 'hello';
};

var Service = ng.core.Injectable().Class({
  constructor: [ OtherService, function (service) {
    this.service = service;
  }],

  test: function() {
    return this.service.test();
  }
});

var AppComponent = ng.core
  .Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    template: '<div>Test: {{message}}</div>',
  })
  .Class({
    constructor: [Service, function (service) {
      this.message = service.test();
    }],
  });

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
  ng.platform.browser.bootstrap(AppComponent, [
    OtherService, Service
  ]);
});
```

In your case, I think that your forgot to add `app.database` in providers. Something like:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
  ng.platform.browser.bootstrap(AppComponent, [
    app.database
  ]);
});
```

You could also have a look at this question:

- [Dependency Injection in Angular 2 with ES5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34644887/dependency-injection-in-angular-2-with-es5)

Comment: Ive come across a question with this. in angular one you could have a kind of shared service so that variables could be shared across components via the service is that possible in angular 2? i mean the injector is working but it creates two separate instances of the same service rather then sharing it between two constructors.

Comment: never mind i figured out that when you inject it with the bootstrap then its shared but when you inject it using a component provider its a unique instance

Comment: Yes, it's because of hierarchical injectors. See this question for more details: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34804298/whats-the-best-way-to-inject-one-service-into-another-in-angular-2-beta/34807397.